# Ask questions with attributes and functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, random, attributes

This is my code:

```
class People:

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"A('{self.name}', {self.age})"

    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

def sortlist():
    people = []
    file = open('people.txt', 'r').readlines()

    for k in file:
        k = k.split()
        people.append(People(k[0], float(k[1])))
    people.sort(key=lambda c: (c.age, c.name))
    g = 0
    for g in range(len(people)):
        people[g].height = g + 1
return people

def question_height():
    for i in sortlist():
            print(random(i[0]))

def question_name():
    for i in sortlist():
        for i in range(0,104):
            print(random.choice(i.name))
```

The last part of the code (after return people) does not work the way I want it to. I want the question_height function to pick out a random number from the height attribute and the question_name function to pick out a random name from the name attribute.

Does anyone have an idea on what I could do to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are fine only with `random.choice` function. It takes a sequence of items and it randomly chooses one of them. First, you have to transform your list of `People` objects to list of names or heights. Then, just pass the list to the `random.choice` function.

```
def question_height():
    all_heights = [person.height for person in sortlist()]
    print(random.choice(all_heights))

def question_name():
    all_names = [person.name for person in sortlist()]
    print(random.choice(all_names))
```

Another option is pass the list of Person objects directly to `random.choice` and then just print its name or height.

```
def get_random_person(people):
    return random.choice(people)

def question_height():
    people = sortlist()
    random_person = get_random_person(people)
    print(random_person.height)
    
def question_name():
    people = sortlist()
    random_person = get_random_person(people)
    print(random_person.name)
```